# Convert Image Using imagecreateformpng having errors

Tags: php, image, colors

This is my code for selecting an image, and then converting that image into several colours and then posting them to a directory on my server. I am having some issues with the "if($im && imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, $colour->RGB))" part of the query. IF i put in an actual RGB code in the "$colour->RGB" part it works. However the RGB saved in the database is saved correctly, this is the result of the query.

White
255,255,255
White shading failed.

Green
0,255,0
Green shading failed.

Orange
255,165,0
Orange shading failed.

Red
255,0,0
Red shading failed.

Pink
255,51,153
Pink shading failed.

Blue
0,0,255
Blue shading failed.

Silver
192,192,192
Silver shading failed.

Yellow
255,255,0
Yellow shading failed.

```
<?php

include('PATH_TO/ez_sql_core.php');
include('PATH_TO/ez_sql_mysql.php');

$db = new ezSQL_mysql('xxxx','xxxx','xxxx','xxxx');

$colours = $db->get_results("SELECT Colour, RGB FROM colours");

foreach($colours as $colour)
{
    echo $colour->Colour;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $colour->RGB;  
    echo "<br>";

    $im =     imagecreatefrompng("IMAGE_URL");

    if($im && imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, $colour->RGB))
    {
        echo "Image successfully shaded {$colour->Colour}.";

        imagepng($im, "images/Convert/IMAGENAME-{$colour->Colour}.png");
        imagedestroy($im);
    }
else
    {
        echo "{$colour->Colour} shading failed.";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Can anyone advise why $colour->RGB will show correctly on the echo yet not on the "if($im && imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, $colour->RGB))"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Per the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php) the RGB colour values need to be provided as separate arguments:

```
list($red,$green,$blue) = explode(',', $colour->RGB);

imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, $red, $green, $blue);
```

Answer (score -1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php

From the manual COLORIZE filter needs individual R G B values. You are passing  string.

Convert imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, $colour->RGB)

To

$ rgb = explode ($color-> RGB);
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, $rgb [0], $rgb [1], $rgb [2] );

Comment: Bad `explode()` syntax.

Comment: Thanks @cOle2.  I know I forgot the glue. Will do better next time.